# Interesting uses of "Bier" in compound nouns

Tags: meaning, compound

I'm familiar with the terms "Wegbier" and "Konterbier", but wondered if there are any other examples of -Bier being added to other compound nouns to describe it being drunk in specific situations?

Comment: Wegbier is also commonly referred to as Fußpils, which is a pun on Fußpilz (foot fungus) and the [pils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilsner) you drink while walking on foot.

Comment: Wegbier is more common. ngram knows no Fußpils https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wegbier%2CFu%C3%9Fpils&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feierabendbier fällt mir noch ein.

---

There is also After-work beer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are. The [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/?q=*bier) lists some<sup>1</sup> that can be found in official text corpora: *Konterbier* (which you already mentioned), *Schankbier*, *Freibier*, *Stehbier*. But there are more, as other answers have shown. In fact, you can easily produce such compounds yourself: [*Weihnachtsbier*](https://www.bierentdecker.com/magazin/artikel/148/weihnachtsbiere-und-winterbiere), [*Winterbier*](https://www.bierentdecker.com/magazin/artikel/148/weihnachtsbiere-und-winterbiere), [*Hochzeitsbier*](https://www.google.com/search?q=hochzeitsbier&rlz=1C1NHXL_deDE801DE801&oq=hochzeitsbier), [*Frühstücksbier*](https://www.stern.de/lifestyle/leute/jenny-schmelzer-goennt-sich-ein-fruehstueckbier-7235910.html), [*Trostbier*](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/trostbier/?hl=de), [*Entspannungsbier*](https://www.morgenpost.de/familie/article104035973/Entspannungsbier-Partydrinks-Komasaufen.html) …

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Notice that several items in the DWDS list, such as *Aerobier* or *Barbier*, are not compounds at all.</sup>

Comment: None of them refers to beer drunk in a specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Other examples are

- Frustbier, see [here](https://www.welt.de/newsticker/dpa_nt/infoline_nt/sport_nt/article146333899/Storl-hakt-Saison-ab.html)
- Wohlfühlbier, see [here](https://www.rhoenundsaalepost.de/lokales/aktuelles/art2826,443455)